# update multiple rows in jtable with batch?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

is it possible to update multiple rows in jtable using batch.. if yes then how? if not is there any other solution? i mean update statement here not insert!
thanx in advance

```
   try {
    int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
        cc.c.setAutoCommit(false);

        String sql = "Insert into employyes(idemployyes,employyesName,employyesAge,employyesAddress) values (?,?,?,?)";
        cc.pst = cc.c.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            String idemployyes = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
            String employyesName = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
            String employyesAge = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
            String employyesAddress = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);

            cc.pst.setString(1, idemployyes);
            cc.pst.setString(2, employyesName);
            cc.pst.setString(3, employyesAge);
            cc.pst.setString(4, employyesAddress);

           cc.pst.addBatch();
            cc.pst.executeBatch();
            cc.c.commit();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the answer:

```
 try {
        int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
        cc.c.setAutoCommit(false);
        String sqlquery = "UPDATE employyes\n"
                + "SET employyesName = ?,employyesAge = ?, employyesAddress = ?\n"
                + "WHERE idemployyes = ?;";
        cc.pst = cc.c.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            String idemployyes = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 0);
            String employyesName = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 1);
            String employyesAge = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
            String employyesAddress = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 3);


            cc.pst.setString(1, employyesName);
            System.out.println(employyesName);
            cc.pst.setString(2, employyesAge);
            System.out.println(employyesAge);
            cc.pst.setString(3, employyesAddress);
            System.out.println(employyesAddress);
            cc.pst.setString(4, idemployyes);
            System.out.println(idemployyes);

            cc.pst.addBatch();
            cc.pst.executeBatch();
            cc.c.commit();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```